# How to remove a double entry from the ADFS properties

Tags: powershell, adfs

I was working on SSO with ADFS on Win Server 16, and I did the following command twice by accident:

```
Set-AdfsProperties -WIASupportedUserAgents (
    (Get-ADFSProperties | Select -ExpandProperty WIASupportedUserAgents) + "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT"
)
```

the problem is, now my `Get-AdfsProperties` shows a double entry of `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT)`, resulting in an SSO & SAML authentication error.

How can I get rid of the double entry?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help :) i had issues with the code probably something at my end but i tried the following code

`Set-AdfsProperties -WIASupportedUserAgents "MSAuthHost/1.0/In-Domain", "MSIE 6.0", "MSIE 7.0", "MSIE 8.0","MSIE 9.0", "MSIE 10.0", "Trident/7.0", "MSIPC", "Windows Rights Management Client","MS_WorkFoldersClient","=~Windows\s*NT.*Edge"`

basically i added everything but mozilla and it worked back to normal